# Testing a hypothesis in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

Suppose you have 3 pieces of information about new born babies, their weight, the gestation period and if the mother had hypertension or not (1 or 0).

Hypertension affects baby weight in one of two ways:

1. Indirectly, by causing a shorter gestation period, and
2. Directly, by reducing baby weight even if the gestation period is the same.

Fit a model in R to investigate the hypothesis that maternal hypertension causes babies to be born earlier.

I interpreted the hypothesis to "Is babyweight the same regardless of hypertension, if the gestation period is the same" so I believe I need to include all 3 variables in the `lm` function, but I am not sure which would be the independent variables and which would be the dependent variable. I also had the idea to plot all of the points on a scatter graph, and to colour the hypertension ones differently, but I am not sure how to do this in a "linear model" and feel that actual numbers from the summary function would be of use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your information, combined with my layman "domain knowledge", I'd assume that we are considering the following (possible) causal relationships:

1. Longer gestation period $\rightarrow$ higher baby weight (let's call it $w$);
2. Maternal hypertension $\rightarrow$ shorter gestation period ($t$); and
3. Maternal hypertension $\rightarrow$ lower baby weight.

You can encode the hypertension $h$ as a binary dummy variable, taking values $0$ and $1$ and try to fit a linear model:

$$
t = \beta_0 + \beta_w w + \beta_h h + \beta_{wh} (w \cdot h) + \epsilon
$$

Physically, this might seem implausible (we are used to understand the right-hand side of the equation being the cause and the left-hand side the effect), but mathematically it's perfectly OK.

If either one of the $\beta_h$, $\beta_{wh}$ is significantly non-zero, then your hypothesis is proven.